# Are objective change random?

Tags: warframe

Sometimes during missions your objective changes, I have tried Spy missions turning in Extermination missions, Capture missions turning in to Spy missions etc.

Is this random or a preset event for some missions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is random. Your mission starts off with a base objective, but always has a chance to either A) Finish your objective, and a new one pops up, or B) start an objective, have it cancelled and replaced with a new one.